# Update date + one year in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

When I want setting numerical value +1 in mysql table, I use e.g.:

```
UPDATE table SET number=number+1 WHEN ...
```

How can I set date + one year?

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You could use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) : (or [ADDDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) with `INTERVAL`)

```
UPDATE table SET date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 20):

This post helped me today, but I had to experiment to do what I needed. Here is what I found.

Should you want to add more complex time periods, for example 1 year and 15 days, you can use

```
UPDATE tablename SET datefieldname = curdate() + INTERVAL 15 DAY + INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

I found that using `DATE_ADD` doesn't allow for adding more than one interval. And there is no YEAR_DAYS interval keyword, though there are others that combine time periods. If you are adding times, use `now()` rather than `curdate()`.

Answer (score 7):

For multiple interval types use a nested construction as in:

```
 UPDATE table SET date = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

For updating a given date in the column `date` to 1 year + 1 day