# Update Date column with adding 10 days in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table name "coupon" .. and a column name "enddate"

I have to add 10 days in all the data of enddate

```
SELECT enddate, DATE_ADD( enddate, INTERVAL 45 
DAY ) AS enddate
FROM coupon
```

this is working , I want to replace the current data with this resultant data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update date + one year in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865019/update-date-one-year-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update coupon set enddate = date_add(enddate, interval 45 day)
```