# YII2 get the date after 10 years and 5 years

Tags: mysql, yii2-advanced-app

Here is the table structure.

tbl_staff

```
firstname varchar(50)
midname varchar(50)
lastname varchar(50)
...
```

tbl_staff2

```
first_day_of_service date
...
```

Here is the scenario.
For the first 10 years of stay of the staff in organization, he/she will be given a loyalty award and then every 5 years after he/she receives the first 10 years.

My initial code will just get the name of staff and the date of first day of service.

```
public function actionGet_loyalty() {

        $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['firstname', 'midname', 'lastname', 'first_day_service'])
                ->from('tbl_staff')
                ->limit(100)
                ->offset(0)
                ->orderBy('first_day_service')
                ->leftJoin('tbl_staff2', 'tbl_staff2.staff_id = tbl_staff.id');
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        $string = "<table class='table table-striped'><tr><th>No.</th><th>Name</th><th>Date to Receive Loyalty Award</th></tr>";
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $midname = $row['midname'];
            $lastname = $row['lastname'];
            //$string.=$row['first_day_service'];
            $string.="<tr>"
                    . "<td>$i</td>"
                    . "<td>" . $firstname . " " . $midname[0] . ". " . $lastname . "</td>"
                    . "<td>" . $row['first_day_service'] . "</td>"
                    . "</tr>";
            $i++;
        }
        $string.="</table>";
        return $string;
    }
```

How to display all the name of staff and the date  he/she will receive the award in increasing order.

Or any mysql query that will sort the name according the date?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it via SQL query, in MySQL you can add date using [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```
DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
```

Check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865019/update-date-one-year-in-mysql).

Or via PHP using `DateTime` [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
$dateTime->modify('+ 5 years')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: but the problem is that it should be 10years on the first time then every 5 years onward.  Is it good to just make a mysql function that will return the date for next award then call that function in the query  and set `order by` on that function?

Comment: @quickbrownfox It can be calculated via both MySQL and PHP. It's up to you and depends on situation.