# sql date ... get full year behind?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i need help for a function ... what i want to do is get the quantity of year behind of a date chosen .... for example i write '12-12-2017' ... so it will back year behind 'til '12-12-2016' i guess ?? any help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update date + one year in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865019/update-date-one-year-in-mysql)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks but none of the those function worked for me ....

Comment: Then you're not using MySQL.

Comment: select DATEADD(year,-1,'12-12-2017') this one worked for me

Comment: `DATEADD` is SQL-server

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DATE_ADD('2017-12-12', INTERVAL -1 YEAR)`

Comment: thanks man but they give me red line .... date_add is not allowed for me

Comment: select DATEADD(year,-1,'12-12-2017') this one worked for me

Comment: `DATEADD` is SQL-server @AzouzRh

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah i just made mistake to choose the right tag i guess thanks anyways

Comment: `DATE_ADD` is MySQL, `DATEADD` is MS-SQL. Your tag says `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple to use is

```
SELECT '2017-12-12' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

demo http://rextester.com/SUM99725

Comment: i found this one it worked for me .... thanks any way boss                                           select DATEADD(year,-1,'12-12-2017')