# How to get next year from current date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

How can increase one year to current date in mysql database , to be more clear example i have this date `2020/09/13` this current date i want to this date in the next year to be like that : `2021/09/13`

Comment: Day `32`? i think you meant `23` right?? try `SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 YEAR` ?

Comment: thank you it's working correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865019/update-date-one-year-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date('1986/09/11') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR DT from dual
```

needs to work.