# Get the next occurrence of a day/month after today using mysql

Tags: mysql

Given a date in the past how can I get the next occurrence of the day and month in that date in the future?

For example,

If the date today is **2019-04-17**

Given a date of **2015-02-27** I'd like to use mysql to manipulate the date to return **2020-02-27** i.e given the 27th February 2015, what is the next occurrence of the 27th February after today?

or

Given a date of **2016-06-18** I'd like to use mysql to manipulate the date to return **2019-06-18** i.e given the 18th June 2016, what is the next occurrence of the 18th June after today?

Essentially I'm asking how to add a year onto a date until that date is in the future

Comment: What is the logic here? What is the relation between `2015-02-27` and `2020-02-27`? Both are different days

Comment: Do you mean the same week-day and the same date?

Comment: the logic here is around finding the next renewal date for an annual subscription type product my company sells. i only have the date the product was bought on and I'd like to find the next occurrence of that date. `2015-02-27` and `2015-02-27` are different days but they are both the 27th of february @Crazy2crack

Comment: not (necessarily) the same week-day, just the same date. @B001ᛦ

Comment: What's the logic to find  `next renewal date for a annual subscription`?

Comment: On your updated question, `27th Feb` comes every year. So how are you expecting it to be in `2020`? why not `2016`?

Comment: simply look on "how to add one year to a date in mysql". Plenty of answers here and in google

Comment: @Crazy2crack because the subscription will end in 2020, 2016 is in the past. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update date + one year in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865019/update-date-one-year-in-mysql)

Comment: @Lelio Faieta that's not what OP is asking if one year later is in the past.

Comment: ha @AGR gets it. I'm looking to add a year to a date until that date is in the future. Apologies for the wording of my question, reading it back I can see it's pretty unclear!

Comment: ok got it now. Thanks @AGR :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to calculate how many years from that date to now:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_past, CURDATE())
```

will give you that information.
You look for that date in the future so it should become:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_past, CURDATE())+1
```

Finally you can calculate the date in the future:

```
UPDATE table SET renewal_date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_past, CURDATE())+1) YEAR)
```

Untested but should do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

If to be taken your example deliberately, you can manipulate the dates using `INTERVAL`. Very simple really. Just something like this can work:

```
SELECT '2015-02-27' + INTERVAL 5 YEAR; -- Would return you '2020-02-27'.

SELECT '2016-06-18' + INTERVAL 3 YEAR; -- Would return you '2019-06-18'.
```

**EDIT:** I can think of one way to achieve you condition. Hopefully will give you some ideas ;)

```
SELECT CURDATE() AS 'Current Date',subscribe_date,
IF(DATE_FORMAT(subscribe_date,'%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d'),
CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 YEAR),DATE_FORMAT(subscribe_date,'%m-%d')),
CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(CURDATE()),DATE_FORMAT(subscribe_date,'%m-%d'))) 'Next_occurance' FROM
(SELECT '2018-09-27' AS 'subscribe_date' UNION 
SELECT '2015-02-27') a;
```

Comment: That does not answer to OP's question though. He wants the query to take into account if the interval is sooner than today.

Comment: i appreciate that solution solves the examples given in the question but those examples were just there to illustrate the problem. the date to be manipulated could be any date in the past 10 years so I would need to add a dynamic amount of years to that date until it returns a date in the future

Comment: I'm misunderstanding yet another question, sigh... Sorry for that

Comment: my fault @tcadidot0 ! was having a tough time trying to word the question succinctly

Comment: @tcadidot0 that works for Feb 27th but if I was to plug in, say, September 18th it would return 2020-09-18 but i would need it to return 2019-09-18 as that's the next occurrence of 18th September after today

Comment: ok, thanks for the input @dbatten .. I'm getting more understanding now :)