# PHP/SQL Update on String

Tags: sql

I have an sql field issue_code data type string with the following sample data format "2020-12-0012" with hundreds of records i want to update all from "2020" to "2021" without modifying the rest of the record. how can i query this?

Comment: Are you sure it's "2020-12-0012" with two zeros in last group?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: sorry the field is not a date but a unique string. i just need the right query on how to do this on mysql.

Comment: Found it.. $query = UPDATE table_name SET issue_code = REPLACE(issue_code, '2020', '2021') WHERE issue_code LIKE '%2020%';

Answer (score 1):

If your field is DATE, [this could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865019/update-date-one-year-in-mysql)

If your field is text, you could use this
Please, check date format

```
#example for MySQL

UPDATE Test.test_table
SET
    issue_code=DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(issue_code, '%Y-%m-00%d'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%Y-%m-00%d')
# you may add this condition
# WHERE
#    YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(issue_code, '%Y-%m-00%d')) = '2020'
;
```

**UPD:**
Be careful with leap years

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Found it.. $query =  UPDATE table_name SET issue_code = REPLACE(issue_code, '2020', '2021')
WHERE issue_code LIKE '%2020%'