# This is what I have so far just stuck in how I do the invoice_due_date

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated

Use a correlated subquery to return one row per vendor, representing the vendor’s oldest invoice (the one with the earliest date) that is due within the next 2 weeks.

Each row should include these five columns:

| vendor_name | invoice_number | invoice_date | invoice_due_date | invoice_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

This is what I have so far just stuck in how I do the `invoice_due_date`:

```
SELECT vendor_name, invoice_number, invoice_date, invoice_total 
FROM vendors v JOIN invoices i 
WHERE invoice_date <= ( SELECT Min(invoice_date) 
    FROM invoices JOIN vendors ON v.vendor_id = v.vendor_id )
GROUP BY vendor_name, invoice_number, invoice_date, invoice_total;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update date + one year in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865019/update-date-one-year-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the meaning of _"due within the next 2 weeks"_. I'm assuming that `invoice_date` won't be in the future so how do you calculate when is the due date from that? Do you have "terms" on how many days until the invoice due? Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69774119/edit) with some (fake) sample data?